# adding 'dispatch' to a redux action breaks action (w/out dispatch the action runs)

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, redux-thunk, dispatch

I am using redux with redux-thunk middleware. The function in question makes a GET request to an API and upon response (`.then()`) dispatches the `res` to my redux store via an action.

For some reason when I pass `dispatch` to the parent function the function never runs. When I remove `dispatch` the parent function does run...(???) I have multiple other components within the same app that follow this exact same pattern successfully. For some reason this particular component is behaving in this strange way although i've triple checked and the boilerplate is all the same.

Here is my `store.jsx`:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/root_reducer'

const configureStore = (preloadedState = {}) =>
    createStore(
        rootReducer,
        preloadedState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
    );

export default configureStore;
```

my actions `my_team_actions.js`:

```
import * as APIUtil from '../util/api/my_team_api_util';

export const RECEIVE_ORG_SURVEY = "RECEIVE_ORG_SURVEY"

export const receiveOrgSurvey = survey => ({
    type: RECEIVE_ORG_SURVEY,
    survey
});

export const getOrganizationSurvey = () => dispatch => {
    debugger 
    APIUtil.getOrgSurvey()
        .then((res) => {
            debugger
            dispatch(receiveOrgSurvey(res))
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

my API call `my_team_api_util.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getOrgSurvey = () => {
    return axios.get(`/api/mongo/organizations/test`)
}
```

component container `my_team_container.jsx`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MyTeam from './my_team';
import { getOrganizationSurvey } from '../../actions/my_team_actions';

const mSTP = state => {
    return {
        user: state.session.user,
    };
};

const mDTP = dispatch => {
    return {
        getSurvey: () => getOrganizationSurvey(),
    };
};

export default connect(mSTP, mDTP)(MyTeam);
```

component `my_team.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyTeam extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.createTeam = this.createTeam.bind(this);
    }

    createTeam() {
        this.props.getSurvey();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="my-team-frame frame">
                <div className="my-team-container">
                    <div className="contact-data-container">
                        <div className="contact-data-header header">Contact a Data Scientist</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="myteam" onClick={this.createTeam}>BUTTON</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyTeam;
```

On the client side the `my_team` component renders fine and when I click the button which calls the function which will eventually dispatch my action it only seems to run when `dispatch` is NOT included in `getOrganizationSurvey()` in `my_team_actions.js` i.e. I hit both debuggers (and the second one with a correct `res` object). When `dispatch` is included (as shown in the snippet above) I don't hit either debuggers nor are any errors thrown.

I'm really scratching my head on this, any input is appreciated!

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 1):

God I am a moron... XD

I said I triple checked... I should have checked 4 times! The issue was in my components container `my_team_container.jsx` I simply forgot to pass dispatch in the map dispatch to props object!

I fixed it by adding `dispatch` to the getSurvey callback...

`my_team_container.jsx`

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MyTeam from './my_team';
import { getOrganizationSurvey } from '../../actions/my_team_actions';

const mSTP = state => {
    return {
        user: state.session.user,
    };
};

const mDTP = dispatch => {
    return {
        getSurvey: () => dispatch(getOrganizationSurvey()),
    };
};

export default connect(mSTP, mDTP)(MyTeam);
```

it's funny how you can spend 2 hours on a problem, think it's hopeless and then as soon as you ask for help take another look at it and the solution just stares right back at you